# Filtering calculated values with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am trying to filter the values of 'BMI', such that I'm left with all values less than 35. However, when executing this (see code) I end up with a 248x19 (i.e. the imported file) matrix with some (for me unexplainable) NaN values inside of it, instead of getting a single column of filtered 'BMI'-values, which I ultimately want.

Code in pycharm:

```
df = pd.read_csv('BodyFat.csv', sep=';',decimal=',')
df['BMI'] = 703*df.WEIGHT/(df.HEIGHT**2)

df_filter = df[df['BMI'] < 35]

print(df_filter)
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Eub.png)

[Edit* Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCN0.png)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your dataset in text format so that it is reproducible?

Comment: @jaberg it is because of the NaN values too. you might try :- `df[(df[''BMI'] < 35) & (df['BMI'].notnull())]`

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj Since the entire sheet is pretty large, and I found no way of including an excel file in my question, I'm afraid i'm not entirely sure how im supposed to do that.

Comment: Just paste a sample of it. Print a sample of your dataframe and then copy and paste the outputs

Comment: @KarthickMohanraj I've included a picture of the generated outputs

Comment: Please attach at least a link to your input csv file. Without it, there's no way we could reproduce your error

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this might be due to NaN values :

```
new_data = df[(df[''BMI'] < 35) & (df['BMI'].notnull())]

len(df) 
len(new_data)
```